# PHP: mail() function with runtime ini_set() for SMTP and SMTP_PORT not working on Linux

Tags: sendmail, php, ini-set

I have used a PHP code for Mailing using a SMTP HOST as given below:

```
        ini_set('SMTP','myserver');
ini_set('smtp_port',25);
$to = $email;
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$headers  .= "From: NO-REPLY<no-reply@mydomain.com>" . "\r\n";
$subject = "Confirmation For Request";
$message = '<html>
                <body>
                    <p>Hi '.$firstname.' '.$lastname.'</p>
                    <p>
                        We recieved below details from you. Please use given Request/Ticket ID for future follow up:
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Your Request/Ticket ID: <b>'.$ticketID.'</b>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                    Thanks,<br>
                    '.$team.' Team.
                    </p>
                </body>
            </html>';
mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
```

Now When i execute the code in Windows Localhost..  I am succcesfully recieving the mail whereas, If I deply the same code on my Linux setup, I do not recieve anymail, though the mail() function returns true in linux machine as well....

On looking into the phpinfo for both windows localhost and Linux server, for mail parameters I found a single difference,

In Windows I found sendmail_path == "No Value", whereas on linux server it says, "usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i"

Could some one help me to resolve this issue?

NOTE: In windows, its a WAMP setup, whereas Linux is a Dedicated server...

Comment: Which MTA server do you use on your Linux? (sendmail/postfix/exim/...)

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to your `php.ini` there is a short description that

```
ini_set('SMTP','myserver');
ini_set('smtp_port',25);
```

This both values are only for Windows. So if you want to send mails over SMTP on linux you have to install postfix for example and build a relay.

https://www.linode.com/docs/email/postfix/postfix-smtp-debian7

Or what is really much easier use a lib that can send SMTP mail over socket or curl like Swiftmailer.

http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html

Thats much easier and its working.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a look at this before and in PHP.ini there are two keys `sendmail_from` http://php.net/sendmail-from (For Win32) and `sendmail_path` http://php.net/sendmail-path (For Unix) on a wamp or similar setup for linux the default of this key is me@localhost which when on an actual mail server it should reject that email address as a user as they don't exist on the server.

Try adding something like...

```
ini_set('sendmail_from','admin@example.co.uk')
```

Comment: So Whats the conclusion?

Comment: Check what the current sendmail_from is set to in php.ini and if this needs to be dynamic you should add in ini_set('sendmail_from','admin@example.co.uk') or something similar

Comment: What is it currently set to? also is there mail server running on the same machine aka localhost?

Comment: It was initially set to "No Value", I used "ini_set('sendmail_from','noreply@mydomain.com')",. Could you tell me how to find out which Mail server is installed?

Comment: I have SMTP installed

Comment: You can use ini_get to get the current configuration key - or the default in php.ini so i tend to do something like if( ini_get('smtp_server') != 'myserver' ) ini_set('smtp_server', 'myserver');

Comment: It would depend on the setup of the server if you are managing the server and you don't know i would guess there isn't one but if it is hosted you are best asking which one is installed however using noreply@mydomain.com if this account does not exist you will hit the same issue

Comment: I did ini_get('SMTP'), I recieved output as "localhost"

Comment: do you know if there is a local mail server actually running?