# how to send email to godaddy hosted emailid using PHP and angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm developing an ionic app, in which i need to send feedback to the specific email id, for that I,m using php as server side code, I tried PHPMailer, and php mail() function but unfortunatly nothing works... please help me solve this problem...

here is my service.js

```
sendEmailFunction: function(feedbackUser) {
            var data = {    
                            userEmail: feedbackUser.userEmail,
                            feedback: feedbackUser.feedback,
                            sendToMail: feedbackUser.sendToMail };
            var link = 'http://localhost/endpoints/sendEmail.php';
            return $http.post(link, data);
        }
```

here is controller.js

```
$scope.sendFeedback = function(feedbackUser) {
                AllServices.sendEmailFunction(feedbackUser)
                .then(function(response) {
                    console.log("success");
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });   
    };
```

here is .php file

```
<?php
    include ("connection.php");

    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

    $userEmail = $data->userEmail;
    $feedback = $data->feedback;
    $sendToMail = $data->sendToMail;
    $resp = array();

        $to      = $sendToMail;
        $subject = "test anjali";
        $message   = $feedback;
        $Header = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        $Header .= 'From: Customer <$userEmail>' . "\r\n";
        ini_set('SMTP', "relay-hosting.secureserver.net");
        ini_set('smtp_port', "25");

    if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $Header)) {
        $resp['STATUS'] = '_SUCCESS';
    }

    else {
        $resp['STATUS'] = '_FAIL';
    }

    echo json_encode($resp);
?>
```

I'm not getting why m not getting an email in godaddy hosted email service.. please help me....

Answer (score 1):

Because you're not concatenating the $userEmail.
Replace this:

`$Header .= 'From: Customer <$userEmail>' . "\r\n";`

With this:

`$Header .= "From: Customer <".$userEmail.">" . "\r\n";`

Comment: nothing happens.... I'm not getting mail... do i need to change settings in php.ini file ?

Comment: Could be that your server is not windows... Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29455560/1104753

Comment: Have you tried by using the default setting of the server? So by omitting the `ini_set` 2 times

Comment: Remove the following bits of code: `ini_set('SMTP', "relay-hosting.secureserver.net");` and `ini_set('smtp_port', "25");` This code will change the default setting of the server, so by removing that it will use the default settings.

Comment: please help me.. i'm stuck here since from last three days

Comment: console is returing  _SUCCESS

Comment: That would mean the `mail()`-function is working, might be a much more difficult to debug issue with blacklists, junk-filters, auth-failures or whatnot

Comment: so, what do i need to do for that?